# How to get file's path as user input in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, encryption

This is my code for any file encryption and decryption. However this will work if the file (which user want to encrypt/decrypt) and this script are in the same directory.
I want user should give its file's input with its path.
I would appreciate your help!!

This is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is a simple file encrypter and decrypter"
echo "Please choose what you want to do: "

choice="Encrypt Decrypt"

select option in $choice; do
    if [ $REPLY = 1 ];
    then    
            echo "You have selected Encryption"
            echo "Please enter the file name"
            read file;
            gpg -c $file
            echo "The file has been encrypted"
    else 
            echo "You have selected Dcryption"
            echo "Please enter the file name"
            read file2;
            gpg -d $file2
            rm $file2
            echo "The file has been decrypted"   
    fi
done
```

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: You want the user to enter the full path, or you want the user to enter just the filename and the script will look in its own directory?

Comment: I want user to enter the full path